# C# & LINQ; Grouping files into 5MB Groups

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings, I'm trying to write a Linq query to run on a list of filenames which returns a list of files Grouped into 5MB chunks. So each group will contain a list of filenames whose total/summed MB is 5MB maximum.

I'm okay with Linq but this one I don't know where to begin. Help

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo (@"x:\logs");
List<string> FileList = di.GetFiles ("*.xml")
var Grouped = FileList =>
```

Comment: Are there any more constraints? Like minimal count of groups? If yes, then LINQ is really bad idea, because such algoritm is too complex.
If no. Then LINQ is only bad idea. LINQ should be used only when you imediately know how to write your query. If you need to think a lot about how to make your query, solving it iteratively would be much safer and quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this with LINQ.

```
var groupedFiles = files.Aggregate(
    new List<List<FileInfo>>(),
    (groups, file) => {
        List<FileInfo> group = groups.FirstOrDefault(
           g => g.Sum(f => f.Length) + file.Length <= 1024 * 1024 * 5
        );
        if (group == null) {
            group = new List<FileInfo>();
            groups.Add(group);
        }
        group.Add(file);
        return groups;
    }
);
```

This algorithm is greedy. It just finds the first list it can shove the `FileInfo` into without blowing past the upper bound of 5MB. It isn't optimal in terms of minimizing the number of groups but you didn't state that as a constraint. I think an `OrderBy(f => f.Length)` before the call to `Aggregate` would help but I don't really have time to think deeply about that right now.

Comment: thanks for the response, could you show the imperative perspective please?

Comment: @ZionGates: Actually, I think the LINQ solution is kind of okay. The imperative solution wouldn't be much different.

Comment: I think this solution is imperative one. You are only replacing foreach with Aggregate. Rest is normal imperative code.

Comment: @Euphoric: Agree, which is why I am okay with this solution and stated the imperative solution wouldn't be much different.

Comment: This seems to be the most straightforward approach presented, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq) to start with.  It addresses grouping into sublists.  The trick then is detecting the size of the files in the `group by` clause.  This may be an answer where *not* using LINQ may be clearer than using it.

Part of the problem is that you have a list of file *names*.  You need a list of the File objects so you can query the size of the file through LINQ.  In Linq 4.0 you have a [group-by-into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) construct that should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

1. Define a type that takes a file size as input and returns a value which increments as a specified max is reached and resets. (This type is responsible for maintaining its own state.)
2. Group by the values returned by this type.

Code example:

```
// No idea what a better name for this would be...
class MaxAmountGrouper
{
    readonly int _max;

    int _id;
    int _current;

    public MaxAmountGrouper(int max)
    {
        _max = max;
    }

    public int GetGroupId(int amount)
    {
        _current += amount;
        if (_current >= _max)
        {
            _current = 0;
            return _id++;
        }

        return _id;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const int BytesPerMb = 1024 * 1024;

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"x:\logs");
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.xml");

var grouper = new MaxAmountGrouper(5 * BytesPerMb);
var groups = files.GroupBy(f => grouper.GetGroupId((int)f.Length));

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    long totalSize = g.Sum(f => f.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Group {0}: {1} MB", g.Key, totalSize / BytesPerMb);
    foreach (FileInfo f in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} ({1} MB)", f.Name, f.Length / BytesPerMb);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would first throw the file list to a SQL table.  Something like this but with the size column included:

```
CREATE TABLE #DIR (fileName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #DIR
EXEC master..xp_CmdShell 'DIR C:\RTHourly\*.xml /B'
```

Then it would be a select statements something like:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN SIZE < 5 THEN 1
WHEN SIZE < 10 THEN 2
...
END AS Grouping
FROM #DIR
ORDER BY Grouping, FileName, Size
```

There is a security setting you have to change real quick on SQL Server to do this. See the blog posting [HERE.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2010/11/18/Uploading-XML-Files-to-SQL-Server.aspx)